# Xampp Mysql PhpmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Вылезла ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'users' is read only in C:\xampp\htdocs\check.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\check.php(21): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `us...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\check.php on line 21
```

Предполагаю что ключевые слова `table 'users' is read only`, вот только как сделать его не `read only` не знаю, казалось что в `phpmyadmin` можно и это исправит ситуацию, но не нашел там такого.

вот код html и связанный php:

1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Форма регистрации</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styleregistration.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h1>Форма регистрации</h1>
        <form action="check.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Введите логин"><br>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Введите имя"><br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Введите пароль"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Зарегистрировать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. 

```
<?php
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина логина";
    exit();
    } else if(mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 50) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина имени"; 
    exit();
    } else if(mb_strlen($pass) < 2 || mb_strlen($pass) > 6) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина пароля (от 2 до 6 символов)";
    exit();
    }

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123123', 'register-bd');
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`)
    VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");

    $mysql->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле конфигурации **MySQL**, например здесь `C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf`, поставьте `innodb_force_recovery = 0`

Comment: Поставил, не изменило ситуацию, также пробовал innodb_force_recovery = 1, так же